# Python Unit Tests Import Issue

Tags: python, unit-testing, aws-lambda, software-design, aws-serverless

I am currently working on a Python application with the following directory structure. In this case, `app.py` imports `mongodb_service.py` locally, which in turn references `secrets_manager_service.py`.

```
functions
    __init__.py
    mongodb_crud_service
        __init__.py
        app.py
        mongodb_service.py
        secrets_manager_service.py
```

I have begun writing tests from the project root:

```
tests
    __init__.py
    mongodb_crud_service_tests
        __init__.py
        unit
            __init__.py
            test_lambda.py
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to run unit tests from the root of my project (`python -m unittest discover`). `test_lambda.py` references the service modules via global imports (e.g. `from functions.mongodb_crud_service import app`). Whenever I run the unit tests in this manner, I receive the following error, ostensibly due to the local imports: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mongodb_service'`. Does anyone have any tips?

My application is an AWS SAM application, so it is structured like this.